# mysql-connector-python freezes with unstable network

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I am quite new to this.
I found out my WiFi gets funky around the time the DHCP-leases are renewed every day.
So while coding on my project containing mysql-connector sometimes when the quary takes to long the whole program freezes and never (or only after 10 minutes or so) recoveres. While searching I only found timeout values for the connection or select quarys but nothing that helps me solve my freezing problem during a update quary.
Thanks in advance

I tried to:
set connection timeout, but connection is already established at this point so this does not help.
set session max execution time, but i have read this is only for select statements

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.